# Let a compact group $G$ act on a manifold $M$. Why does G act as a group of automorphisms on $H^p (M, \mathbb{R})$?

Tags: homology-cohomology, global-analysis

Let $(\sigma , m) \rightarrow t_{\sigma}$ be this action. A definition for acting on a group of automorphisms I found here: [Action via automorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644022/action-via-automorphism).
t^{*}_{\sigma} seems to be this action and I can prove, it is an action, but do not how to prove the property making it an action of automorphims, because I do not know how the group action of the de Rham cohomology works / how to work with it.

Comment: Doesn't the compact group act naturally (and continuously, in whatever relevant sense) on all spaces of differential forms? What is your context?

Comment: I think I wrote down all the requirements, the context in genereal is on Bredon, p. 307, it is about differential forms on Lie groups and cohomology of compact Lie groups.